# Using the standalone package with a FMT file

Tags: standalone, format-files

I am trying to use TeX's ability to dump a "format" file along with the `standalone` package. There are four scenarios to consider, and I can get all but 1 working.

First - the files I'm using. There is `pre.tex`, which loads all my packages and will get turned into my format file. It has the following contents:

```
%&PDFLATEX
\makeatletter\@ifclassloaded{standalone}{}
  {\documentclass[class=report]{standalone}
    \usepackage{standalone}
    \def\preambledocclass{}}\makeatother
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Next, I have `main.tex`, which includes one file, `sub.tex`:

```
%&pre
\makeatletter\@ifundefined{preambledocclass}{%%
  \documentclass[class=report]{standalone}
  \usepackage{standalone}
  \input{pre}}{}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{main}
\input{sub}
\end{document}
```

Finally, I have `sub.tex`, which does not include any other files:

```
%&pre
\makeatletter\@ifundefined{preambledocclass}{%%
  \documentclass[class=report]{standalone}
  \usepackage{standalone}
  \input{pre}}{}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{sub-document}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to be able to compile `sub` independently of `main`. Additionally, I want to create a FMT file out of `pre` and have both `sub` and `main` use that format file (if present).

To create the FMT file, I run `pdflatex -ini pre \dump` .

Notice that `main` and `sub` both input `pre`; However, when `pre.fmt` is available, `pre` is effectively inputted before `main` or `sub` begin. The check for `preambledocclass` at the beginning of `sub` and `main` detects when `pre.fmt` has been loaded.

There are four scenarios to consider, depending on if `pre.fmt` is available.

1. `pre.fmt` NOT available:

   1. `pdflatex sub` -- Success.
   2. `pdflatex main` -- Success.
2. `pre.fmt` available

   1. `pdflatex sub` -- Success.
   2. `pdflatex main` -- I get the following error:

      ```
      (./sub.tex

      ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

      See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
      Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
       ...

      l.6 \begin{document}

      ?
      ```

If I change `sub` so it declares a `documentclass` when `pre.fmt` is loaded, as in:

```
%&pre
\makeatletter\@ifundefined{preambledocclass}{%%
  ...}{\documentclass{standalone}}\makeatother
```

Then I can no longer compile `sub` independently (Scenario 2.1). I get a double documentclass declaration error. Adding a check to see if `\documentclass` equals `\@twoclasseserror`, as in:

```
%&pre
\makeatletter\@ifundefined{preambledocclass}{%%
...}{\ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror\else\documentclass{standalone}\fi}\makeatother
```

fixes `sub`, but breaks `main` (Scenario 2.2), resulting in an ugly error:

```
(./sub.tex
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\sa@gobble ...reamble@\sa@filepath \endcsname {#1}
                                                  \@ifundefined {sa@written@...
l.6 \begin{document}

?
```

How do I successfully compile all 4 scenarios above?

BTW, I am using Version v0.4a – 2011/04/07 of `standalone`.

Comment: You are using the `standalone` *class* together with the *package* for both the main and the sub file. Are you sure that is what you want? If the main file is a normal document you should use the `report` class directly and only load the `standalone` package. Also note that v1.0 is out since 2011/12/21 and that the `standalone` package redefines `\documentclass`, which might be a cause for trouble here.

Comment: Also using the `geometry` package with the `standalone` class is a little suspicious. That normally doesn't make much sense, because the class is mostly about cropping the content making a predefined page geometry unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you need a `\documentclass` in your `sub` file, so that its preamble is skipped. The skipping code is part of the redefined version of `\documentclass`. If that macro is never executed the `\begin{document}` is never redefined and causes the usually error. You need to add some `\documentclass` in all cases when the sub file is compiled as part of the main document.
Because you are using the `standalone` class for both the main and sub file you can't use the normal if-switches and macros provided by `standalone` because they are true in both cases.

The idea would be to check if `\documentclass` is equal to `\@twoclasseserror`, but you must not enclose the `\documentclass` inside any `\if... \fi` clause, because the `\fi` will be skipped then with the rest of the preamble. You need to change your code to close the if-clause before `\documentclass` is processed.

Please note that the `\section` command will cause trouble when used with the `crop` option new in v1.0 *and* selected as default. You should therefore set the `preview` option explicitly (it is the default for version v0.x).

Here the three files with the required changes:

#### pre.tex

```
%&pdflatex
\makeatletter\@ifclassloaded{standalone}{}
  {\documentclass[class=report,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{standalone}
    \def\preambledocclass{}}\makeatother
\usepackage{geometry}
```

#### main.tex

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\def\preambledocclass{}
\begin{document}
\input{sub}
\end{document}
```

#### sub.tex

```
%&pre
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{preambledocclass}{%%
  \documentclass[class=report,preview]{standalone}
  \usepackage{standalone}
  \input{pre}
}{%
 \ifx\documentclass\@twoclasseserror
    \expandafter\@gobble
 \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
 \fi
 {\documentclass{standalone}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{sub-document}
\end{document}
```

Tested with both v0.4a and v1.0 of the `standalone` bundle.

Note that you must write `%&pdflatex` in `pre.tex`, not `%&PDFLATEX`, otherwise you will get an error under case-sensitive operation systems like Linux.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Would it also work to assign `\documentclass{standalone}` to a token register in the `\else` case above, and then expand the token register after the conditional?

Comment: Awesome answer! One question though, what do the comments, `%&pdflatex` and `%pre` do?

Comment: @Born2Smile: You can select the "format" using these comments. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172818/2975 for more details.