# What is "%&-line parsing enabled"?

Tags: pdftex, texlive

My `latex` logs begin with

```
 %&-line parsing enabled
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What do you find missing? A minimal working example? (any attempt generates this log message) Or perhaps my question is just too short?

Comment: Don't be alarmed. Your question is fine. That message is just our way of welcoming a new user (see [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)).

Comment: @Jubobs although the fact that you need to explain that implies that it's an unnecessarily negative opening comment I think. The text block ought to be changed (if it is going to be used).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some TeX engines (e.g. based on Web2C) have the feature that the format file can also be specified in the first line of the document, e.g.:

```
%&pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

This specifies the format `pdflatex.fmt` for the engine `pdftex`. The engine still needs to be specified, e.g. `pdftex`, `pdflatex`, `latex`, but the format is taken from the first line of the document. Thus the document above can also be compiled with

```
pdftex test
```

or

```
latex test
```

In both cases the LaTeX format is used and PDF is generated.

From the manual page of TeX:

> **`-parse-first-line`**
>   If the first line of the main input file begins with `%&` parse it   to look for a dump name or a
>   `-translate-file` option.
>
> **`-no-parse-first-line`**
>   Disable parsing of the first line of the main input file.

Answer (score 9):

%& parsing is an option which allows one to indicate which TeX variant a particular file requires, e.g., `%& eplain`