# Using a template and sty-file from a website

Tags: packages, compiling

I am trying to prepare my manuscript according to the instructor given in http://mb.math.cas.cz/MBinstr.html. I downloaded the template and the sty-file. I put the same in the same direction but couldn't success. The PDF-file is not generated at all. The message:

*Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "IMjournal".tex \Process exited normally* appear.

Comment: So the pdf should had be created in the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that in the top of the [`IMjournal.tex`](http://mb.math.cas.cz/IMjournal.tex)-file that you linked, the first line is `%&latex`. This would cause `pdflatex` to compile a `.dvi` instead of a `.pdf`. See the question: [What is "%&-line parsing enabled"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172812/what-is-line-parsing-enabled) for more info on this.

Anyhow, the `.dvi`-file should be fine readable, but if you want a pdf, removing the top line should suffice.